# What are hardware "gates" in the context of the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, system-calls, variadic-functions, ioctl

> In user space, the ioctl system call has the following prototype:
>
> ```
> int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long cmd, ...);
> ```
>
> The prototype stands out in the list of Unix system calls because of the dots, which usually mark the function as having a variable number ofarguments. In a real system, however, a system call cannot actually have a variable number of arguments. System calls must have a well-defined prototype, because user programs can access them only through hardware "gates".

So what are these hardware gates? The page numbers are 135 and 136.

Comment: System call are getting executed by the help of registers. It's quite lengthy. You can read the chapter "system calls" of book LinuxKernelDevelopment by Love for a complete understanding.

Comment: To anyone else trying to find the answer: [you can find the referenced book online.](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/ch06.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardware "gates" are specific instructions that allow switching to the kernel's context, usually to let a program request something from the kernel. This might be an instruction like `syscall`, `sysenter`, or `int 0x80`, depending on your system.

I should note that these aren't usually called "hardware gates" in practice, but rather something like "system calls instructions."